# Tracking Simple Objects in Low Sampled Simple Images

Tags: image, image-processing, tracking, sampling

I'm tracking clouds dropping rain over Malaysia. The sampling rate is once every 3 hours (each time the satellite orbits the earth it takes a pictures). These are simple objects that are easily thresholded however they vary in size, shape and distance moved. It is easily human visible where the clouds are moving if you look at 3 or 4 frames but I'm not sure where to begin when tracking these type of objects. They don't have any particular features that stand out or remain constant frame to frame.

Comment: What exactly are you working with ? Where are the (sample) inputs ?

Answer (score 0):

If the clouds are the only part of the pictures that are movin it can be detected with background subtraction. There are several methods to do this please see this link for overview

http://www-staff.it.uts.edu.au/~massimo/BackgroundSubtractionReview-Piccardi.pdf